# Asterisk Call Manager/1.3 Mssing action in request

Tags: asterisk

I have installed asterisk on my centos WHM server, but when i try to access it from my browser it gives me error saying

```
Asterisk Call Manager/1.3
Response: Error  
Message: Missing action in request
```

I am accessing it like

```
http://server-ip-address:5038/asterisk/static/config/index.html
```

Please help!!

Answer (score 0):

That error mean you are not using it correct.

Most likly you have no web files in directory described in config.

For most comprehensive example of such interface i can recommend you download older versions of AsteriskNow distro.

But it is highly not recommended use asterisk internal web server unless you forced to.